# How to get class of type

Tags: c#, generics

I need to use method like:

```
DoSomething<(T)>();
```

But i don't know which Type i have, only object of class Type. How can i call this method if I have only:

```
Type typeOfGeneric;
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Could you give a more concrete example?

Comment: We're going to need more details than that...maybe a code example or two would help.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, really, you can't both edit a man's post trying to clarify it how you imagine it to be, AND complain that the post isn't clear... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a Type specified as a Type, you'd have to build the generic method, and call it via reflection.

```
Type thisType = this.GetType(); // Get your current class type
MethodInfo doSomethingInfo = thisType.GetMethod("DoSomething");

MethodInfo concreteDoSomething = doSomethingInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeOfGeneric);
concreteDoSomething.Invoke(this, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

You use reflection (assuming `DoSomething()` is static):

```
var methodInfo = typeOfGeneric.GetMethod( "DoSomething" );
methodInfo.Invoke( null, null );
```

EDIT: Your question changes while I wrote the answer. The above code is for a non-generic method, here it is for a generic class:

```
var constructedType = someType.MakeGenericMethod( typeOfGeneric );
var methodInfo = constructedType.GetMethod( "DoSomething" );
methodInfo.Invoke( null, null );
```

And here it is for a static generic method on a non-generic class:

```
var typeOfClass = typeof(ClassWithGenericStaticMethod);

MethodInfo methodInfo = typeOfClass.GetMethod("DoSomething",   
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

MethodInfo genericMethodInfo = 
    methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeOfGeneric });

genericMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { "hello" });
```

Comment: I think you did not get my question. How to pass Type object as generic parameter?